# Reinstalling Windows on a Thinkpad X201

Tags: windows, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad X201 with a new HDD, so the original Windows installation has been lost. What is the easiest way to reinstall Windows on the new drive (and ideally reuse the Win 7 pro license - there is a label at the bottom of the laptop)?

Answer (score 3):

Download ISO file of Windows 7 pro from below links:

1. [Windows 7 Professional English 32-bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59183.iso)
2. [Windows 7 Professional English 64-bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59186.iso)

Now burn the ISO file to DVD or USB ( minimum size of 4GB required ), You can use Windows 7 DVD/USB tools to burn your iso, you can download it from this link:[Windows 7 DVD/USB tools](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe)

Now **boot** your PC from DVD/USB and **install/reinstall** your windows and give your Product key from COA sticker located on back or side of PC tower, bottom or under battery of notebook.

[image: COA Product key]

Comment: Other Win7 download links are listed in http://superuser.com/questions/78761